# elseif search query not working

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I have a search form that has 3 elements 
keywords, Industry ( Dropdown ) & location

I am trying to create  search function that will query the DB if all 3 elements are selected or based on individual values OR a combination of any elements having $_POST data submitted

Its just not working

My code for the queries is below

```
        if(isset($_POST['keywords']))
    {
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $viewq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`title` LIKE '%$keywords%' OR `description` LIKE '%$keywords%') LIMIT 0,50");
    $resultsfor = $_POST['keywords'];
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['location']))
    {
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $viewq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`title` LIKE '%$keywords%' OR `description` LIKE '%$keywords%') AND (`location` LIKE '%$location%') LIMIT 0,50");
    $resultsfor = $keywords .' jobs in '.$location;
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['industry']))
    {
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $catno = $_POST['industry'];
    $viewq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`title` LIKE '%$keywords%' OR `description` LIKE '%$keywords%') AND (`location` LIKE '%$location%') AND (`catno` = '$catno') LIMIT 0,50");
    $resultsfor = $keywords .' jobs in '.$location;
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['industry']) && empty($_POST['location']))
    {
    $industry = $_POST['industry'];
    $viewq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE `catno` = '$industry' LIMIT 0,50");
    $resultsfor = $_POST['industry']. ' jobs';
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['industry'])&& isset($_POST['location']))
    {
    $industry = $_POST['industry'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $viewq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`catno` = '$industry') AND (`location` LIKE '%$location%') LIMIT 0,50");
    $resultsfor = $_POST['industry']. ' jobs in '.$location;
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['location']))
    {
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $viewq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`location` LIKE '%$location%') LIMIT 0,50");
    $resultsfor = $_POST['location']. ' jobs';
    }

    $view = mysqli_fetch_assoc($viewq);
```

Would really appreciate some help, Ive spent loads of time on this
Thanks in advance

** It does pull data although not correct, If i search for warehouse ( leave industry dropdown blank ) but set location to Leicester it still queries ALL results not Leicester
If I select an Industry from the dropdown menu and leave other fields blank, I get all jobs in all categories not just the category selected

Getting myself confused now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine your issues are due to the complicated way you have structured your if-else conditions. A much simpler way would be to do it as follows...

```
// Get the input variables
$keywords = (isset($_POST['keywords']) && strlen($_POST['keywords']) > 0) ? $_POST['keywords'] : null;
$location = (isset($_POST['location']) && strlen($_POST['location']) > 0) ? $_POST['location'] : null;
$catno = (isset($_POST['industry']) && strlen($_POST['industry']) > 0) ? $_POST['industry'] : null;

$whereUsed = false;
$whereString = "";
$resultsfor = "";

// Add to the WHERE clause if keywords exists.
if ($keywords !== null) {
    if (! $whereUsed) {
        $whereString .= 'WHERE ';
        $whereUsed = true;
    } else {
        $whereString .= ' AND ';
    }
    $whereString .= "(title LIKE '%{$keywords}%' OR description LIKE '%{$description}%')";
    if ($catno === null) {
        $resultsfor .= $keywords;
    }
}
// Add to the WHERE clause if catno exists.
if ($catno !== null) {
    if (! $whereUsed) {
        $whereString .= 'WHERE ';
        $whereUsed = true;
    } else {
        $whereString .= ' AND ';
    }
    $whereString .= "(catno = '{$catno}')";
    $resultsfor .= $catno;
}
// Add to the WHERE clause if location exists.
if ($location !== null) {
    if (! $whereUsed) {
        $whereString .= 'WHERE ';
        $whereUsed = true;
    } else {
        $whereString .= ' AND ';
    }
    $whereString .= "(location LIKE '%{$location}%')";
    if ($catno === null && $keywords === null) {
        $resultsfor = "{$location} jobs";
    } else {
        $resultsfor .= " jobs in {$location}";
    }
}

// Build the SQL query using the WHERE clauses we've built up
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM listings {$whereString} LIMIT 0, 50";

// Execute the query and fetch the response
$viewq = mysqli_query($con, $sqlQuery);
$view = mysqli_fetch_assoc($viewq);
```

There is no need for the if-else-if format you have in your original code. You are simply adding `WHERE` clauses based on whether or not a variable is set... so you should do exactly that.

Please note that in your code, and in my example the SQL queries are vulnerable to SQL injection. I strongly suggest looking into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Excellent Tom !
Many thanks.. I over complicate things and thats where it usually falls apart
Also regarding SQL injection.. I agree, although the user querying the DB has NO other priviledges apart from SELECT.. no UPDATE or anything else :) ALSO the user has no other access to other DB's 
But I 100% agree prepared statements are better

Comment: No problem Chris. It's often useful to step back from the code and think about what you are actually trying to do rather that jump straight into code!

Comment: 1 last quick q .. 
after my queries I have $resultsfor  ( see my post ) 
How would I put this in with the code you provided ?

Comment: I have updated my answer... Also, if you would like to look into packages that generate the SQL queries for you and execute them using prepared statements then you can check out https://github.com/TomWright/ExtendedPDO. It's a package I use in my personal projects when interacting with MySQL databases! The query builder included uses logic like that in my answer to build the queries so it could be interesting for you to have a read.

Comment: Absolute diamond ! Thanks & have just realised I have your Git already bookmarked :)

Comment: Getting error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' in C:\AppServ\www\midlandjobs\results.php on line 6

This lines throw errors
$keywords = isset($_POST['keywords'] && strlen($_POST['keywords') > 0) ? $_POST['keywords'] : null;
$location = isset($_POST['location'] && strlen($_POST['location') > 0) ? $_POST['location'] : null;
$catno = isset($_POST['industry'] && strlen($_POST['industry') > 0) ? $_POST['industry'] : null;

Comment: I just updated the lines that set `$keywords`, `$location` and `$industry`. Try again now

Comment: strange lol I added the closing ] but it just threw up another error.. code now working perfectly . Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144843/discussion-between-chris-yates-and-tom-wright).

Comment: That's  the way to go. You can shorten and simplify your code a lot, if you collect your "where" parts in an array and implode (" AND ", $where) it at the end. This will skip a lot of this inner if clauses. No need for $whereUsed ... Just a remark :)

Answer (score 1):

I see some erros in your if statements. You should test from most specifc to low restricted. Your first `elseif` for example will never happen, because in this case the first `if` always occours.

Comment: Have updated my post above, also i previously had if statements & not elseif statements but still same issue

Answer (score 1):

There should be nine combinations to filter your query. Your conditions should be

```
if(isset($_POST['keywords']) && !isset($_POST['location']) && !isset($_POST['industry'])){}
elseif(isset($_POST['keywords']) && !isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['industry'])){}
elseif(isset($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['location']) && !isset($_POST['industry'])){}
elseif(isset($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['industry'])){}
elseif(!isset($_POST['keywords']) && !isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['industry'])){}
elseif(!isset($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['location']) && !isset($_POST['industry'])){}
elseif(!isset($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['industry'])){}
```

Comment: i just edited my code and removed isset and replaced with !empty and also empty ( where needed and works too )

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (isset($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['location']) && 
     isset($_POST['industry'])) {
     $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
     $location = $_POST['location'];
     $catno = $_POST['industry'];
     $viewq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`title` LIKE '%$keywords%' OR `description` LIKE '%$keywords%') AND (`location` LIKE '%$location%') AND (`catno` = '$catno') LIMIT 0,50");
     $resultsfor = $keywords . ' jobs in ' . $location;
  } elseif (isset($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['location']) && 
    empty($_POST['industry'])) {
           $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
      $location = $_POST['location'];
      $viewq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`title` 
     LIKE '%$keywords%' OR `description` LIKE '%$keywords%') AND (`location` 
      LIKE '%$location%') LIMIT 0,50");
    $resultsfor = $keywords . ' jobs in ' . $location;
    } elseif (isset($_POST['keywords']) && empty($_POST['location']) && 
     empty($_POST['industry'])) {
      $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
      $viewq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`title` 
      LIKE '%$keywords%' OR `description` LIKE '%$keywords%') LIMIT 0,50");
      $resultsfor = $_POST['keywords'];
   } elseif (empty($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['industry']) && 
   empty($_POST['location'])) {
     $industry = $_POST['industry'];
     $viewq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE `catno` = 
    '$industry' LIMIT 0,50");
     $resultsfor = $_POST['industry'] . ' jobs';
  } elseif (empty($_POST['keywords']) && isset($_POST['industry']) && 
     isset($_POST['location'])) {
     $industry = $_POST['industry'];
       $location = $_POST['location'];
     $viewq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE (`catno` = 
     '$industry') AND (`location` LIKE '%$location%') LIMIT 0,50");
    $resultsfor = $_POST['industry'] . ' jobs in ' . $location;
} elseif (empty($_POST['keywords']) && empty($_POST['industry']) && 
isset($_POST['location'])) {
       $location = $_POST['location'];
           $viewq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE 
     (`location` LIKE '%$location%') LIMIT 0,50");
      $resultsfor = $_POST['location'] . ' jobs';
   }

     $view = mysqli_fetch_assoc($viewq);
```

please try this

Answer (score 0):

I tried to minimize your code and check this and tell if it works correct or not

```
<?php

    //Enter your code here, enjoy!
    $query          = "SELECT * FROM listings ";
    $eQuery         = "";
    $resultsfor     = "";

    if(isset($_POST['keywords']) && !empty($_POST['keywords']){
        $eQuery     .= " (title LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['keywords'])."%' OR description LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['keywords'])."%') ";
        $resultsfor .= $_POST['keywords'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['location']) && !empty($_POST['location']){
        $eQuery     .=  " (`location` LIKE '%".addslashes($_POST['location'])."%') ";
        $resultsfor .= ' jobs in '.$location;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['industry']) && !empty($_POST['industry'])){
        $eQuery     .= " (`catno` = '".$_POST['industry']."')";
        $resultsfor = (isset($_POST['keywords']) && (isset($_POST['location'])))? $_POST['keywords'] .' jobs in '.$_POST['location'] ;
    }

    $query = mysql_query($con, $query.$eQuery." LIMIT 0,50");

    $view = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```